# Why there is a minimal element of this set

Tags: algebraic-curves

I'm trying to understand this proof:

[image]

I know intuitively, but Why formally there is such a minimal element?

I need help

Thanks

Comment: That's from Fulton's book on [Algebraic Curves](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) no? The answer to your question is exactly above the theorem you are sharing with us, i.e. between the Lemma and Theorem 2 on page 8.

Answer (score 0):

Because we are supposing this set is non-empty and $\mathbb A^n$ is noetherian, the result follows easily.